# Drop rows in Pandas DataFrame by Column values (text)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to return a new dataframe by dropping a row from dataframe using their respective text values. And only keeping ones that are blank (or whitespace). So far I can only find ways of either dropping NA, NULLS, by index or complete column. Please suggest way(s) how can
I achieve this result.

Below is the value_count of column  'Category' -

```
                                4091
ZeroClicks                      1342
Duplicate                        257
ZeroClicksDuplicate              139
NoKeywordDuplicate                16
NoKeywordZeroClicksDuplicate      12
NoKeyword                          1
Name: Category, dtype: int64
```

Comment: As it looks like you have homogeneous "empty spaces": `out = df[df['Category'].eq('')]`? Or whatever the value of `df['Category'].value_counts().idxmax()` is

Comment: @mozway This works!!  # `out = df1[df1['Category'].eq('')]`
But, I'm unable to do `out['Category'].value_counts().idxmax()`

ERROR is ; `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Sorry, rather try: `out['Category'].value_counts().index[0]`, but this should give you `''` ;)

Comment: @mozway Should I replace ' ' value, when I created these in previous method and try your method after that?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but `out = df1[df1['Category'].eq('')]` is enough. The other bit was to determine the kind of space in case this wasn't `''`.

Comment: @mozway Okay, I got it. I was getting it wrong that time.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df.loc[df['col_containing_whitespace'].str.contains('^\s+$',na=False)]
```

or

```
df.loc[df['col_containing_whitespace'].str.contains('^\s*$',na=False)]
```